# Fluent NHibernate Dictionary mapping problem

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have following entities

```
public class Entity1
 {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IDictionary<Guid, Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Entity2
 {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IDictionary<Guid, Entity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
 }
```

DB table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLinks](
  [Entity1Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [Entity2Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [LinkItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
 )
```

and following mappings:

for Entity1

```
mapping.HasManyToMany<Entity2>(rc => rc.Entities2)
  .Table("EntityLinks")
  .ParentKeyColumn("Entity1Id")
  .ChildKeyColumn("Entity2Id")
  .AsMap<Guid>("LinkItemId")
```

for Entity2

```
mapping.HasManyToMany<Entity1>(rc => rc.Entities1)
  .Table("EntityLinks")
  .ParentKeyColumn("Entity2Id")
  .ChildKeyColumn("Entity1Id")
  .AsMap<Guid>("LinkItemId")
```

adding data works fine and I can get and see Entity1.Entities2 populated but Entity2.Entities1 is not populated.

Any suggestions why this might be?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably wrong but you can try:

```
mapping.HasManyToMany<Entity2>(rc => rc.Entities2)
  .Table("EntityLinks")
  .ParentKeyColumn("Entity1Id")
  .ChildKeyColumn("Entity2Id")
  .AsMap<Guid>("LinkItemId")
  .Inverse()
```

and

```
mapping.HasManyToMany<Entity1>(rc => rc.Entities1)
  .Table("EntityLinks")
  .ParentKeyColumn("Entity2Id")
  .ChildKeyColumn("Entity1Id")
  .AsMap<Guid>("LinkItemId")
  .Cascade.All();
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but unfrtunately not solved my problem :(